# Is there a way to make two vectors the same length when one uses the other?

Tags: matlab, vector, plot

I'm writing a script to calculate the **[Ackerman steering geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_steering_geometry)** of a car.

**Input:** `T` is linear set of numbers

**Output:** `a` uses `T` to calculate some numbers *that I can plot*.

Within my output there are several other functions that also contain `T` as an input.

**How do I make it** so that my final output is the **same size** as my input?

I've tried pulling out all the inner functions and replacing them with their equations but I still got the same error.

```
fprintf("\nGraph 1");
W = input("\nEnter your W: ");
T = linspace(0.5, 2.2, .01);
Tp = input("Enter your Tp: ");
R0 = 6.1 - T/2;

figure(1);
plot(find_a(W, R0, T, Tp), T, 'LineStyle', '-', 'Color', 'k', 'LineWidth', 2.0);
title('Plot of a vs T with R0');
xlabel('T');
ylabel('a');
grid on;
```

```
function x = find_a(W, R, T, Tp)
    % Description: Finds linkage length
    s_i = sin(phi_o(W, Tp) + delta_i(W, R, T));
    x = (delta_i(W, R, T) * phi_o(W, Tp))/ tan(s_i);
end
```

```
function x = phi_o(W, Tp)
    % Description: Calculates steering knuckles extension angles
    x = atan((Tp/2)/W);
end
```

```
function x = delta_i(W, R, T)
    % Description: Calculates inner turning angle
    x = atan(W./(R - T/2));
end
```

I expect that I would get a graph of `a` vs `T` but instead I receive the error:

> Error using plot
>   Vectors must be the same length.
>
> Error in Solar_Car_Wheel_Calc (line 39)
>       plot(find_a(W, R0, T, Tp), T, 'LineStyle', '-', 'Color', 'k', 'LineWidth', 2.0);

Comment: Can you provide examples of your inputs (`W` and `Tp`)?

Comment: Can you simply print out the size of `a` and `T` and update the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main file use

```
T = 0.5:0.01:2.2;
```

and in your find_a function

```
function x = find_a(W, R, T, Tp)
% Description: Finds linkage length
s_i = sin(phi_o(W, Tp) + delta_i(W, R, T));
x = (delta_i(W, R, T) .* phi_o(W, Tp))./ tan(s_i);
end
```

Tested with value 1 for W and Tp.

There are two issues in your code.

First one is you are trying to create a vector with a particular spacing, which should be done using T= start:spacing:end.

Second issue is you are using mrdivide "/" in your find_a function instead of divide "./". See Matlab docs for clarification.